# Add object to array and save the array to async storage react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, caching, react-hooks

Am downloading some files and saving their data to local storage for react native. The download works fine but am trying to save the object data to an array and store the array in local storage. The issue comes in when am trying to save the item. I have to click twice the download button to save the item else the array stays empty on local storage and does not update.

```jsx
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
const [initialElements, setinitialElements] = useState([]);
const [videoid, setvideoid] = useState(0);
      
//Downloading Video file
const downloadVideo = async () => {
    RNFetchBlob.config({
        fileCache: true,
        appendExt: 'mp4',
    }).fetch(
        'GET',
        'https://cdn.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/premium/getty_105/large_watermarked/istock-1083459308_preview'
    ).progress((received, total) => setValue(Math.round((received / total) * 100)).then(res => {
        setvideopath(res.path());
        console.log('Video Complete');
        addElement();
    });
};

const addElement = async () => {
    let ItemData = {
        itemKey: videoid,
        itemName: 'Object ' + (videoid+ 1),
        image: imgpath,
        video: videopath,
    };
      
    //Pushing new object into array

    var newArray = [...initialElements, ItemData];
    setvideoid(videoid+ 1);
    setinitialElements(newArray);
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('cachedvideos', JSON.stringify(initialElements));
    } catch (error) {
        // Error saving data
    }
};
    
return (
    <View>
        <Button title="Download" onPress={downloadVideo}/>
        <View style={{
          alignItems: 'center',
          marginTop: 25,
        }}>
            <AnimatedCircularProgress
                size={25}
                width={4}
                fill={value}
                tintColor="#00e0ff"
                backgroundColor="#3d5875"
            />
        </View>
    </View>
);
```

I just need to update the array on local storage with the new object to be used in another screen.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this due to a minor mistake in your code:

```
var newArray = [...initialElements, ItemData];
setvideoid(videoid+ 1);
setinitialElements(newArray);
try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem(
    'cachedvideos',
    JSON.stringify(initialElements), <-- change to newArray
  );
} catch (error) {
   // Error saving data
}
```

You are saving `initialElements` to local storage, which is the previous value, not the updated value. This is why you need download the video two times: the second time `initialElements` will equal `newArray` during the previous download.

I would also recommend that you update the `itemName` field:

```
const addElement = async () => {
let ItemData = {
itemKey: videoid,
itemName: 'Object ' + (videoid+ 1), <-- remove the + 1
image: imgpath,
video: videopath,
};
```

Otherwise the `itemName` will indicate that this particular item corresponds to the key `videoid + 1`, but that is not the case.